# Windows thumbnail preview with JNA (Java)

Tags: java, winapi, jna, dwm

```
W32API.HWND targetHwnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow("SunAwtFrame", "Frame")
W32API.HWND sourceHwnd = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow("triuiScreen", "EVE")
W32API.HANDLE thumbnailH = new W32API.HANDLE()

NativeLibrary dwm = NativeLibrary.getInstance("dwmapi")
dwm.getFunction('DwmRegisterThumbnail').invoke(targetHwnd, sourceHwnd, thumbnailH)
```

gives me

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x70f34bee, pid=7208, tid=7364
#
# JRE version: 6.0_18-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.0-b13 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [DWMAPI.DLL+0x4bee]
```

I have a feeling I'm doing it completely wrong, but digging in documentation got me nowhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 3rd param is an "out" parameter, and needs to be a pointer to the handle, not the handle itself. So, something like

```
dwm.getFunction("DwmRegisterThumbnail")
  .invoke(targetHwnd, sourceHwnd, new PointerByReference(thumbnailH))
```

Comment: Looks like it's W32API.HANDLEByReference, but thanks for the hint. I thought passing by reference is handled by JNA.